# Mariner Linux install override password requirements

Tags: linux, system-installation, password

When installing Mariner Linux, it refuses to proceed due to the password not being strong enough. This is for a local VM, and password strength doesn't matter. In fact making it different from other VMs requires it to be written down which makes it worse.

Is there any way to override that requirement during install?